# Multiple blocks inside another?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my name inside of another block that contains the website name, but can't figure it out. What can I use?

I'm trying to get my website name with a smaller extension after it, shich works. But then i want my name underneath it without the space in between.

```
<div id="sitename">
  <span id="address">website</span>
  <span id="extension">.blah</span>
  <span id="name">namegoeshere</span>
</div>

#sitename {
  width: 330px;
  margin: 35px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

#address {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: rgb(99,99,99);
}

#extension {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: rgb(99,99,99)
}

#name {
  display: block;
  width: 72%; 
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11.5pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(99,99,99);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Dn/

Comment: How2Margins. Seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you want to achieve

html

```
<div id="sitename">
  <span id="address">website<span id="extension">.blah</span></span>
  <span id="name">namegoeshere</span>
</div>
```

css

```
#sitename {
  width: 330px;
  margin: 35px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

#address {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: rgb(99,99,99);
}

#extension {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: rgb(99,99,99)
}

#name {
  display: block;
  width: 72%; 
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11.5pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(99,99,99);
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Dn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Margins on the name.

```
#name {
display: block;
width: 72%; 
text-align: right;
font-size: 11.5pt;
font-weight: 500;
color: rgb(99,99,99);
margin-top: -20px;
}
```